# cant enable CORS in spring boot data rest

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cors, spring-data-rest

I need to enable global CORS in my spring boot data rest api to prevent getting the following error whenever i call my api from a browser: 
http://localhost:8090/posts?user-id=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.'.

I can type the url into the a browser and receive the correct get response for that resource, yet i cant make the same call from an ajax call in a webpage.

Any ideas what im missing?

My code and config is below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

}

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {

    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**");
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(UserRepository userRepository, PostRepository postRepository,
                              CommentRepository commentRepository, EventRepository eventRepository, VenueRepository venueRepository) {
    return (args) -> {

        User user = new User("fsdsdfsd","sdsdsds","121212");
        userRepository.save(user);

        Venue venue = new Venue("dsaesrdfddgd","aerttyhyyty","yyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
        venueRepository.save(venue);

        Event event = new Event("dsaesrdfddgd","aerttyhyyty","yyyyyyyyyyyyyy",venue,user);
        eventRepository.save(event);

        Post post = new Post("some posts are funny. Some are not.",user, event);
        postRepository.save(post);

        Comment comment = new Comment("commmentntnrnejfnerfdgdfgdfdt", user, post);
        commentRepository.save(comment);
    };
}
```

}

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PostRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Post, Long> {


Page<Post> readBydeletedIsFalseOrderByCreated(Pageable pageRequest);

@CrossOrigin
Post readByIdAndDeletedIsFalse(Long postId);
```

}

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.6.RELEASE")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'project'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

war {
    baseName = 'project'
    version = '0.1.0'
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Comment: Hi there, kindly check this project https://github.com/MFaisalHyder/REST_API
it is completely made using Spring MVC4 with Spring Boot. in your post you are missing setting up filters for your response headers and also have to allow origin methods like GET, POST... to be used from Application. go through project if not understood i will describe in a complete answer.

Comment: thanks very much. ill try this

Comment: did you get it or you want me post detailed answer, but you need to post your project structure as well, as it'll be needed to be change.

Comment: ah well, to be honest, im struggling, although this post really seemed like it had what i wantted.  If you can help me with a more detailed answer i would really appreciate it. As for the project structure....i am currently keeping everything in one package named hello - not a good thing to do, but my project has been scalled right down so i can get the simple things working first - so its ok for now

Comment: problem is things won't be modular if you are working in GOD class. http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ follow their guide to set your project up.!

Comment: i dont really understand...i have exactly the same setup: src/main/java/hello, with all classes inside hello package.

Comment: but interestingly...my old version of this used controllers too, and it automatically used cors. but when using controllers, you dont get automatic building of HATEOAS links so i was advised to move to spring-data-rest. now my links are created automatically, but i cant access my api from a webpage!

Comment: in order to make it usable in angular js call or ajax ones you must have to provide permission for your app, and when ever build apps or apis use ip instead of localhost

Comment: you will, after adding required headers to your Servlet Response. i have used both direct api controller in web page and through api url in angular methods.

Comment: but isnt that the point...that im trying to get spring boot to provide the correect headers so that it becomes cross-origin?

Comment: spring boot is nothing but application development approach which makes you get rid of bloated xml configurations for setting up all server related and application related binding, so you need to provide those settings of web.xml and pom.xml from coding via @ annotations so it is still on us to provide all basic settings for our application

Comment: yes, thats what spring boot does, i am aware of this. what is less obvious is why spring-boot-data-rest projects exist in the first place if they cant be configured to be cross-origin. the only alternative seems to be to build a very bulky project that doesnt use spring-boot-data rest, but manually create controllers and resourceAssemblers where links are added manually rather than being built automatically from  jpa annotations. this is the only way where using the @CrossOrigin has any effect. cant i have cross-origin spring boot data rest project?

Comment: check my answer i found something, might be helpful..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after discussion in comments what i found, you can try this in your **addCorsMappings** method

```
registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8090")
                          .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST");
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt help, but thanks for the suggestion. i find it hard to believe that the people at Pivotal Spring would have bothered to creater spring-data-rest if it couldnt be used in cross origin request. there must be ome wway to do this

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework this will help you

Comment: thanks. there is a section that looks hopeful - certainly its about the alternative filter-based approach for spring boot projects that dont currently support native cors (for example...data-rest lol)! I have to run an errand, but ill try this when i return. ill let you know how it goes. thanks!

Comment: Yes!!! thankyou so much. this worked, basically by using a filter based approach. At this subsection 'Filter based CORS support' I have tried a couple of approaches that were almost identical, but the small differences here solved it! hero of the day!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Well adding this bean helps

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
}
```

Funny enough that spring doesn't allow CORS support on spring boot data rest endpoints using following bean. However it works as intended with other custom endpoints created by developer.

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {

    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this on the global config:

`registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");`

Comment: this seemed promising so i amended this line in my WebMvcConfigurer bean declaration. Unfortunately this made no differrence.

Comment: Weird, that works flawlessly for regular rest endpoints. I don't think you need the @crossorigin annotation with the global config

Comment: Might be a limitation on rest repositories, try using a cors filter. Tomcat ships with one

Comment: Or implement your own very basic one that populates the access control header to *